# How to multiply the contents of table cells via js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to multiply cells content (only numbers) and using  javascript.
The result is to be displayed in cell X

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function zmiana(){
    var x = document.getElementById("rowstawka");
    x.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML=document.getElementById('Stawka2').value;

    var y = document.getElementById("rowgodziny");
    y.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML=document.getElementById('Godziny').value;



}
</script>
```

I'm using the above script to add content to cells in a table.

And here is the table:

```
<table id="tabela">
<tr id="rowstawka">
    <td>Stawka</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>

<tr id="rowgodziny">
    <td>Godziny</td>
    <td>50</td>
</tr>

<tr id="rowPensja">
    <td>Pensja</td>
    <td>-</td>
</tr>

<tr id="rowNetto">
    <td>Pensja Netto</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Can you change the `table` html, like adding classes ? If yes, [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/710z9xd9/).

Comment: nice idea! Thank you :)

Comment: I have posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the html, try using classes to determine which cells contains a number to be calculated:

```
<table id="tabela">
    <tr id="rowstawka">
        <td>Stawka</td>
        <td class="num">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowgodziny">
        <td>Godziny</td>
        <td class="num">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowPensja">
        <td>Pensja</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowNetto">
        <td>Pensja Netto</td>
        <td id="result">x</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then use this simple snippet to make the magic:

```
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".num");
var total = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    total*= Number(numbers[i].innerText);
}

document.getElementById("result").innerText = total;
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/710z9xd9/)**</kbd>

Comment: I have one more question. How to multiply number from   <td id="result">x</td> *12 and result add to

 <tr id="rowroczna">
        <td>roczna</td>
        <td id="roczna">x</td>
    </tr>

Comment: @MichałMasłoń after the `for` loop, `var total2 = total * 12; document.getElementById("roczna").innerText = total2; `